# Regex - Rename files on FTP and rename column values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex, ftp

The regex used to clean the filenames is `preg_replace('/[^\w\._]+/', '_', $fileName);`

I am looking for a way to rename files in a directory on the FTP server *(FTP client allowing bulk renaming using regex? or some php script?)* using that regex.

Also i would like to rename the values for all the rows in a column in the MySQL *(sql query including regex?)*,
for instance if the value is `http://test.com/content/plugins/audio/uploading/uploads/test song - test title 1.mp3` to remove the directory path and keep the basename, and rename it using the same regex.

Output should be `test_song___test_title_1.mp3` in both FTP and MySQL.

Unfortunately i don't have access to SSH.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what is your problem then?..what do you want?..question is very unclear

Comment: i am looking for a way to rename files on the FTP (either through an ftp client or through php script) according to the regex above. Also, rename column values (with an SQL query maybe?) in the same manner.

Comment: Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for help in formulating good SO questions.  You are expected to put some effort into trying to solve your problem and showing your work, not just asking for a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use [SmartFTP](http://www.smartftp.com/) and for this job i used its function ["Bulk Rename"](http://www.smartftp.com/client/features/bulkrename).

Then for the MySQL, i used this query:

```
UPDATE [table]
SET [column] = REPLACE([column], '!', '_'),
    [column] = REPLACE([column], '@', '_'),
    [column] = REPLACE([column], '#', '_'),
    /* add as many as you wish(the same ones as you put in smartftp bulk rename function) */
    [column] = REPLACE([column], '\'', '_'),
    [column] = REPLACE([column], '\\', '_')
```

I hope it's useful to someone.